# I got the Error: Argument not specified for parameter 'index' of 'Public Overloads ReadOnly Default Property Chars(index As Integer) As Char'

Tags: vb.net

I got this error that, Argument not specified for parameter 'index' of 'Public Overloads ReadOnly Default Property Chars(index As Integer) As Char'.. but when i insert the value of namestringn to a text box and re transfer the value from that text box in the place of namestringn then everything is OK.

```
namestringn = dataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(11).ToString().Trim
namestringn = New String((From c As Char In namestringn() Select c Where 
Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
```

Comment: I just want to get only integers from the string of namestringn.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets in `namestringn()` in this line.

```
namestringn = New String((From c As Char In namestringn() Select c Where 
Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray())
```

And replace it with maybe,

```
Dim out As Integer
namestringn = New String((From c As Char In namestringn.ToCharArray Select c Where Integer.TryParse (c, out)).Array())
```

Comment: Please mark the answer if it has solved your issue. You're welcome.

Comment: No no, this is not working this only returns the first character of namestringn.

Comment: What is the value of `namestringn` ?

Comment: This is a combination of character, special character and digit. Thanks.